# flash/AS3 netstream loading/buffering very slow, what am I missing?

Tags: actionscript-3, netstream

My custom movieplayer uses the following code for playing video. It takes a really long time for the clip to start playing, but once it does, you can skip directly to the end.
I have a feeling that there is some knowledge I'm missing in how buffers and preload works. Could somebody send me in the right direcion?

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void {
    connection = new NetConnection();
    connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, doNetStatus);
    connection.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, doIOError);
    connection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, doSecurityError);
    connection.connect(null);
    stream = new NetStream(connection);
    stream.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, doAsyncError);
    stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, doNetStatus);
    stream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, doIOError);
    stream.client = this;
    video = new Video(1024, 576);
    mc = new MovieClip();
    mc.addChild(video);
    stage.addChild(mc);
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    video.attachNetStream(stream);
    stream.bufferTime = 5;
    stream.receiveAudio(true);
    stream.receiveVideo(true);
    stream.play(SITEURL + vidID +".mp4");
}
```

You can see the player in action here: http://joon.be/serve/ngjd_player.swf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the video's weren't streaming because I needed to run QT FastStart on them.
This solved the problem, netstream is now running as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can download `qt-faststart.exe` and then in admin command promt run:

```
qt-faststart.exe "source.mp4" "fixed.mp4"
```

Took about 15-30 seconds for 10 minutes long video.
Credit: https://articulate.com/support/article/mp4-movie-doesnt-begin-playing-until-it-has-fully-downloaded

I also tried this free opensource converter HandBrake with `Web Optimized` checked. (took all 10 minutes to convert)

Comment: Answers should provide solutions to the question, so I removed the parts that weren't actually part of the solution.